# Compiled list of deprecated C++ features in C++11 standard

Tags: c++11

Do you know where I can find a complete list of C++ deprecated features in C++11 standard?

The [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Features_removed_or_deprecated) on wikipedia is not complete. For example, generation of default copy constructor when a destructor is defined  has been deprecated and it is not listed on that page.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: I believe you can find a list in the C++ ISO standard document (e.g. N3337), Annex D.

Comment: @LeoNatan, of course. Try for yourself.

Comment: The question has been put on hold because such questions tend to "attract opinionated answers and spam". I don't think asking for a compiled list of deprecated features has any room for opinions or subjectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the C++ standards document (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

Annexure C - Pages 1232 to 1249

Comment: Thanks, I found what I want in N3337, Appendix D from Micheal's comment above.